# Lazy Loading Values to Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, knockout.js

```
    pfp.services.filterGroups.getNextFilterSetOptions()
        .done(function(values) {
            _.each(values.items,
                function(item) {
                    self.filteredItems.push(item);

                    if (self.selectAll()) {
                        self.tile.selectedValues.push(item.fieldValueId);
                    }
                });
        });
```

I have a lazy loading component in my web app that when scrolling to the bottom of the scrollable div, the aforementioned method is triggered which then pushes new values retrieved from the method to an assortment of arrays.  I feel like iterating over all of these values (which could be hundreds of values) and pushing individually to the assortment of arrays is overkill.  Is there a cheaper and more efficient way of doing this?

**Refactor Attempt**

Is this any better other than being slightly less code?

```
    pfp.services.filterGroups.getNextFilterSetOptions()
        .done(function(values) {
            self.filteredItems(self.filteredItems().concat(values.items));

            if (self.selectAll()) {
                self.tile.selectedValues(self.tile.selectedValues().concat(_.map(values.items, function(item) { return item.fieldValueId; })));
            }
        });
```

Comment: The refactoring is definitely cheaper as you are not doing the self.selectAll in the loop anymore. Personally I think that the question you ask now, is a bit limited for a code review, I would say there is insufficient data to give a meaningfull answer

Comment: You raise a good point in that I do not have to evaluate self.selectAll() for each item anymore.  That in and of itself makes this refactor cheaper and worth it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I cannot say if you needed that check inside the `forEach` loop in the first place. Also, your refactored code seems to have changed `filteredItems` from an array to a function, and I cannot say if that was your intent

Comment: This code is using the knockout js framework and filteredItems is an observable which essentially turns it into a function for evaluation.